# How to style a data- placeholder attribute in SCSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, scss-lint

I am trying to style a `data-placeholder` in SCSS.

I want to change the color of `data-placeholder` from the existing color to dark-grey but my attempts have not been successful, what am I missing? Code below

**HTML5**

```
<optic-select-input id="placeholder" class="dataplaceholder" data-placeholder="Choose or type subject..."  title="Type your subject" ng-model="newMessage.Subject" data-maxlength="50" spellcheck="true">
```

**SCSS**

```
.dataplaceholder{
    @include placeholder(#A9A9A9,"");
}


@mixin placeholder($color, $size:"") {
    &:-data-placeholder{
        color:$color !important;
        @if $size != "" {
            font-size: $size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NirjharVermani  It is data-placeholder not placeholder!!

Answer (score 2):

Add a square brackets like [data-placeholder].

```
@mixin placeholder($color, $size:"") {
  &[data-placeholder] {
     color:$color !important;

    @if $size != "" {
      font-size: $size;
     }
  } 
}

.dataplaceholder{
  @include placeholder(#A9A9A9,"");
}
```

Comment: @mohanbabu Sure it does. Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/fcm2jvjv/
Look at the hierachy, too. Mixins need to defined before their usage. I edited it in my post as well.

Comment: @Fantasteri it is optic-select-input , not plain input

Comment: @mohanbabu "optic-select-input" is no valid HTML5 tag. Anyway, the code I delivered will rendered correctly for the data-placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 0):

***Not related to this specific example in the question***

---

But to anyone that came across this question. If you are doing this, you likely are overriding a component someone else made and cannot modify directly.

You can wrap the component, then target the HTML element that has the data placeholder.

In a React project that I recently worked on, I wrapped the outer component with something like

```
<div className={styles.featureContent}>
```

Then in the SCSS file for my component that used something from a shared component library for form inputs

```
.featureContent {
    // padding

    .subheadline,
    .description {
      // margins

      div[data-placeholder] {
        // you can begin to target this with specificity
    
        &::before {
          // this is what i was targeting for my task.
          // Making the placeholder italic.
    
          font-style: italic;
        }
      }
    }
```